# Multiple Loaders with LoaderManager, not getting right Loader

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have two loaders, one to populate bind returned data to 2 `TextViews` and another to populate a `ListView`. How do I make sure the correct loader loads for each situation? I am getting an error in the where first loader (`WR_VIEW` case) doesn't seem to be created or loading so in the `onLoadFinished()` it returns a "No such column found error" because it is accessing the second loader which doesn't call that column.

Here in my `onCreate` method I set up the adapter for the list view:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.workouts_options);

    String[] uiBindFrom = { ExerciseTable.COLUMN_NAME };
    int[] uiBindTo = { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        getApplicationContext(), 
        R.layout.exercises_row, 
        null, 
        uiBindFrom, 
        uiBindTo,
        CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);    

    final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
    lv.setClickable(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        }
    });

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(WR_VIEW, null, this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(EXERCISE_VIEW, null, this);
}
```

Create my 2 different `CursorLoader`s:

```
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {         
        switch(id) {
            case WR_VIEW:
                String[] projection = { WorkoutRoutineTable.COLUMN_ID, WorkoutRoutineTable.COLUMN_NAME, WorkoutRoutineTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION };    
                return new CursorLoader(this, Workouts.buildWorkoutIdUri(""+mRowId), projection, null, null, null);
            default:
                String[] columns = {ExercisesColumns.NAME, WRExercisesColumns.COLUMN_ID };          
                return new CursorLoader(this, Workouts.buildWorkoutIdExerciseUri(""+mRowId), columns, null, null, null);
        }
    }
```

Bind data to my `TextViews` here and `swapCursor` for the `ListView`:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case WR_VIEW: 
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                mNameText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WorkoutRoutineTable.COLUMN_NAME)));
                mDescriptionText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WorkoutRoutineTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));

                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mNameText.getText());
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mDescriptionText.getText())) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(mDescriptionText.getText());
                }
                cursor.close(); 
            }
        default:
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }
    }
```

Resetting the Loader:

```
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    int id = loader.getId();
    switch(id) {
        case WR_VIEW: 
            break;
        default:
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `0` as the flag instead of `CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER`. The latter flag registers a `ContentObserver` for the `SimpleCursorAdapter`... in other words, it is used when you want the `SimpleCursorAdapter` to listen for changes. However, the `Loader` framework already does this so registering a `ContentObserver` in this case would be totally pointless. Passing `0` as a flag prevents this from happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `onLoadFinished()` you don't have a `break` after WR_VIEW case, so the default clause is getting run as well, passing the wrong cursor to your adapter. (onCreateLoader seems to have a similar issue as well)

Comment: Adding a break does not work. Both cases are supposed to be run because I am initializing two Loaders. The right cursor is being passed to my adapter. The problem is, in my `onLoadFinished()` WR_VIEW case is trying to access the cursor that is being passed to my adapter when it should not.

Comment: because of the missing break in onCreateLoader, the  String[] columns = {ExercisesColumns.NAME, WRExercisesColumns.COLUMN_ID };          
        cur = new CursorLoader(this, Workouts.buildWorkoutIdExerciseUri(""+mRowId), columns, null, null, null);
    } cursor loader is being used for both loader requests.

Comment: I see, you meant in the OnCreateLoader() too. That fixed my problem. Thanks for your help!